# install node 15 on nginx alpine image

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

```
FROM nginx:1.19.9-alpine
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm
```

The version installed is 14.16.1 for the above Dockerfile, is it possible to install node 15.14.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Node.js version 15.14.0, install the [`nodejs-current`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/nodejs-current) package from the edge community repository:

```
apk add nodejs-current=15.14.0-r0 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

This will pin `nodejs-current` to version 15.14.0, so it will not be upgraded by `apk upgrade`. For allowing future upgrade, simply remove the `=15.14.0-r0` part.

The latest [`npm`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/npm) package, 7.9.0, could be installed from edge as well, this time from the edge/main repository:

```
RUN apk add npm=7.9.0-r2 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```

This time, version pinning is required, otherwise apk will pick the stable `npm` version from Alpine 3.13, 14.16.1-r1.

Putting it together, the resulting Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.19.9-alpine
RUN apk add nodejs-current --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community && \
    apk add npm=7.9.0-r2 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
RUN node --version && npm --version
```

Version check for node and npm:

```
/ # node --version
v15.14.0
/ # npm --version
7.9.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works! By the way, is there a repo that has npm@7? The newest one I can get is npm@6.14.12.

Comment: Glad to help @xuezhang. It seems the latest npm package on edge/community is 7.9.0, which was just updated a couple of days ago: [npm](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/npm). I have updated the instructions to include the latest npm package as well.

Comment: Thank you again! I think I finally got how alpine package works.

Comment: Although the webpage shows the newest version is 7.9.0, by running the Dockerfile as you provided in the post, I can only download 6.14.12. If I run "RUN apk add --update npm=7.9.0-r2 nodejs-current=15.14.0-r0 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community". I will get "#5 7.710 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#5 7.740   npm-14.16.1-r1:
#5 7.740     breaks: world[npm=7.9.0-r2]".

Comment: My apologies @xuezhang! I didn't notice npm is at the edge/main repository, as opposed to main/community of node. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you! It works now! Hard to believe we made the same mistake at the same time.